# Intersect two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a rather simple question:

Is there a simple way to adapt the following code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[red, line width = 1mm] (2, 0) -- (-2, 0);
    \draw[blue, line width = 1mm] (0, 2) -- (0, -2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

such that the red line is in front of the blue one and the blue one has a "hole" at the intersection. Without changing the the order in which they are drawn (e.g. the red one first) and without the exact knowledge of the intersection point? Essentially the final product should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why the rule that the red line has to be drawn first? Also, are there other rules or just the two? If there are, what the rules which should be applied to them? The same as for the blue one, or just ignore them?

Comment: Peraphs this link can be an help for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388611/drawing-knots-without-overdrawing-a-grid

Answer (score 2):

In simple cases, tikz options `double=<color>` and `double distance=<dimen>` are useful, accompanied with tikz library `background`. See the following example.

In complex cases, you may need `knots` package, as @Sebastiano suggested in [question comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570233/intersect-two-lines#comment1437135_570233).

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[white, double=red, double distance=1mm, line width=1mm](2, 0) -- (-2, 0);
    \scoped[on background layer] 
      \draw[blue, line width = 1mm] (0, 2) -- (0, -2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am honored to have my name in your answer....:-) +1.

Comment: Could you please help me improve my bounty code if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways. All are simple.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every path/.style={line width=1mm}}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(-1,-1) coordinate (A) 
(1,1)   coordinate (B)
(-1,1)  coordinate (C) 
(1,-1)  coordinate (D);

\draw[blue] (A)--(B);
\draw[white,line width=2mm] (C)--(D);
\draw[red] (C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[teal] (A)--(B);
\draw[orange,preaction={draw,line width=2mm,white}] (C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (intersection of A--B and C--D) coordinate (I);
\draw[brown] (A)--(B);
\draw[magenta,shorten >=1mm] (C)--(I);
\draw[magenta,shorten >=1mm] (D)--(I);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (intersection of A--B and C--D) coordinate (I);
\draw[magenta] (C)--(D);
\path (C)--(I) node[pos=1,sloped,fill=white]{};
\draw[brown] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} % page 178, PGF manual
\draw[cyan] (A)--(B);
\draw[white,double=red,double distance=1mm] (C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```